# ways to incoporate negative or minus sign in variable name

Tags: r, variables

**R** accepts only alphanumeric characters, "dot" and "underscore" in variable names. I had names like `tmax_60_days_Dec13-Feb13_mean` or `tmax_60_days_Dec13-Feb13_tmax:>=:-5`. Used such system, so I can parse select sub strings easily and also because I was calculating rolling means and used these conditions themselves as names :o

Until recently, I have got away with it, using `get` or manually removing the 'apostrophe' which `knitr` added.

But, when I try to use these variables/column names of data fames in functions like `party` or `randomForests`, it backfired. They were not recognised

I can change the colon and hypen to dot or underscore, though I would prefer some other possibility. And the ">=" to "ge" and "<=" to "le". But, how do people code the "negative" or "minus" sign if you want to have it in your variable name or column name of a data frame?

I thought of prefixing the number with "neg" or "minus", but wanted to ask around if there are more *elegant* ways of doing it or simply to know what other ways people mange it.
Thanks

Comment: are these negative signs or hyphens? `tmax_60_days_Dec13.to.Feb13_mean` ?

Comment: the ones in yours - underscores. I used my system to also shorten the variable name as much as possible for plotting purposes. I am willing to use underscores and dots everywhere else, but still would like a nicer solution for the negatives that precede numbers, if there is one.

Comment: I doubt this will be possible in general without rewriting a lot of R functionality. You can have such names and they will work if you quote them `` x$`tmax_60_days_Dec13-Feb13_tmax:>=:-5` `` would be OK. But you have no control once these vectors go into a modelling function, and that will be your downfall. Try simpler names and have a look-up table if you insist on needing to map to the more complex ones.

Comment: :) Thx! I did realise the rewriting-R part! Thought it might be worthwhile to learn how others do it in such situations. With much talk of late about the inconsistencies in R's naming systems, who knows - there might an exit on the other side of the tunnel.

Comment: The other possible thing to consider (and a more robust approach in the long run) is to see if you can use `Hmisc`'s `label()` function. That tries to carry more human-readable information along in a `label` attribute without messing with the column names (which can then stay short and programmer/machine-friendly).

Comment: @BenBolker `HMisc` looks promising, but it seems its use is limited to `HMisc` functions.[Unfortunately the label is only in effect for functions provided by the Hmisc package, such as describe().](http://www.statmethods.net/input/variablelables.html). Will give it a go, nevertheless. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `comment` function:

```
x <- 1:10
comment(x) <- "this is a comment"
 y <- 1:10
 comment(y) <- "this is another comment"
 xy <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
 str(xy)
 #----------------    
 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: atomic  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "this is a comment"
 $ y: atomic  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "this is another comment"
 #--------------
 comment(xy$x) <- "prod"
 comment(xy$y) <- "sum"

interpret <- function(x) eval(parse(text=paste0(comment(x) ,"(",quote(x),")") ) )
lapply(xy, interpret)
#-----------------
$x
[1] 3628800

$y
[1] 55
```

A more expansive response would need a data-object that warrants further testing.

Comment: Thx for introducing `comment` and `quote`. might come in handy sometime. As you say, if I want to have conditions like `tmax>=-2.3` and evaulate it, might get more complex.